# Automatic Detect OTP without show keyboard in IOS

Tags: ios, swift

In general, to get OTP verification code we need to set

```
txtOTP.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

it will automatic display OTP above keyboard like above picture.

[image]

but the requirement that I met is not allow user to typing, it mean only allow user to tap OTP field not keyboard.

so the expect result that I want should be something like this

[image]

Comment: Try setting `txtOTP.inputView` to an empty view. Does that work?

Comment: I'm trying to get **UIKeyboard window** to add **UIView** above the keyboard but it still impossible for me :/

Comment: If you are looking for functionality like Android, auto-read and click button, this is not available in iOS.

Comment: yes it is not avaliable in IOS, you don't have permission to do this either you need to validate passcode from server if its not validate then show alert other wise good to go to next screen

Comment: Hi @Sweeper, as apple document said by using inputView OTP will not work

Comment: @FahimParkar, Chandaboy It seems iOS issue then.

Comment: @Sekny : It's not an issue. It's a security by Apple. Don't worry as Android is improving on security, they will bring this same as iOS too.

Comment: yes @Sekny you are right